# Inverse Square vs Exponential

Tags: terminology, mathematics, dissipation, intensity

I feel a little foolish asking this, but I keep reading sources which say that for an inverse square law relationship, e.g. light intensity vs distance from source, the intensity decays exponentially.

Are inverse square and exponential the same?  I would think not, as I cannot find an algebraic way of writing $I \sim 1/r^2$ in the form of $I \sim \exp(ar)$.  I do know exponential is the same as "geometric" increase (or decrease), as you keep multiplying by the same number every time.

This may be a symptom of the modern informal usage where people say something changing "exponentially" just means "a lot, very quickly" (don't get me started...).  But I know the folks here can set me straight.

Comment: No, they are not the same.

Comment: Although I would be curious about what sources you've seen that say this.

Comment: IMHO, it's bad enough when people abuse "exponentially" like that in an informal context. In a formal context, it's inexcusable. Reading stuff like that totally undermines my trust in a source.

Comment: do you mean, "writing $I \propto 1/r^2$ in the form of $I \propto a^{br}$ for constants $a$, $b$, variable $r$"?

Comment: *One* of the sources I saw this in was talking about radioactive emissions, and they may have been discussing general intensity fall off with distance (which is inverse square) and separately attenuation thru a material (which is exponential)...... This raises the very interesting point of why we don't have to account for these two effects on top of each other.   Even air most have a (small) attenuation factor that is exponential in nature

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Inverse square is not the same as exponential dropoff.  Any source which says this is using "exponentially" in a colloquial way.  Hopefully they don't then try to do mathematics immediately afterwards!

There are some exponential dropoffs in physics, such as the intensity of [evanescent fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evanescent_field), but the drop off of normal light is decidedly an inverse square law and not an exponential law.

Comment: Light drops off both inverse square (as the area covered expands with distance) and exponentially (as in Beer's law for the attenuation of light via absorption).

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Not necessary true for laser beams. The beam area is essentially constant.

Comment: No they are not; they diverge. This leads (at long distances) the intensity fallinw approximately as inverse square. Diffraction also adds an exponential term to the decay which typically dominates at extremely large distances.

Comment: @yarchik Laser light is divergent when so focused, like non-laser light, not by its nature.

Comment: @jp314 Ever heard of self-focusing? Never mind,  this was not main point of my comment. I wanted to make sure that school kids that learn physics with interest and frequent this forum also learn to pay attention to details. The first comment was too black and white, but this is just my personal opinion. I like the answer though (+).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, in exponential equation the variable (x) is in the exponent. In a power function the variable is the base. In inverse square law, the intensity is inversely related to the square of the distance; the distance being the variable. Hence, inverse square law is a power function and not an exponential function.